# Multiline with clause in Python

Tags: python, styles, contextmanager

How can I spread a long `with` clause in Python over multiple lines?  Right now, I have

```
    with self.context_manager_one(some, parameters, that, are, passed) \
            as return_value_one, \
            self.context_manager_two(self.p, slice(None), None) \
            as return_value_two:
```

I would like to follow [Google's Python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Line_length), which proscribes backslash line continuation.

Comment: How about splitting into two context managers first?

Comment: @alecxe: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean just `with ... as return_value_two` inside `with ... as return_value_one`.

Comment: Right, that saves one `\\`, but is there no way to use parentheses to do this?  Looking at the parse tree, it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: I'd just define context managers outside the with statement or use `nested`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html. Hope that helps.

Comment: @alecxe: nested is gone…

Comment: @alecxe: Okay, thanks.  Too bad Python doesn't allow parentheses with  the `with` statement.  It seems an arbitrary limitation.

Comment: You can add `()` around an expression: `with (open("c:\\temp\\23", "w")) as f: pass` worked for me, and so should `with (self.context_manager_one(some, parameters, that, are, passed)) as return_value_one, (self.context_manager_two(self.p, slice(None), None)) as return_value_two:`. There you can add line breaks as you want.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039022/python-multi-line-with-statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python multi-line with statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039022/python-multi-line-with-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in Python 3.10!

https://github.com/we-like-parsers/pegen/issues/229

https://bugs.python.org/issue12782